# Designing a way of allowing users to change the language of a site

Tags: php, localization, internationalization

I have a website written in PHP (all of my functionality is complete) and I am now starting to add the interface. The site allows users to decide which language they want the pages displayed in. The information is stored in a cookie and then a language file is read when needed to display the correct content.

My question is, in terms of design, how could I allow the user to change the language? For example, using a dropdown box or some other method. I am looking for something that looks really good but is also really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdown in a modal confirmation window with overlay effect would be cool.

Comment: Like a jQuery modal confirmation window.  Keep a select language button/link which when clicked will open a modal confirmation window( which will gray out the background page).  You can keep a language dropdown in this window for users to select.  You can have various animations to show/hide this window, which will make it cooler than a regular dropdown on your main page.